# Synchronization of inter process communication between three relative processes

Tags: c, unix, process, signals, posix

I've recently studied the topic of signals and how to use them to help synchronize the processes. I'm trying to write something that will work like Ping-Pong. When there are 2 processes(Parent and Child), i can manage to do it and my code works just fine but when there are 3 processes(Parent, Child and Grandchild), it just doesn't work and i can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, please check my code and  help me. The output should look like this if the input is 10, the program works as it should for the input of 10, however it doesn't work if the input is for example 3,4,5,7,8,9 etc.

grandson 0 
son 1
father 2
son 3
grandson 4
son 5
father 6
son 7
grandson 8
son 9
father 10

EDIT: 
What the program should do: There should be created parent/child and grandchild processes in the program. These 3 processes should communicate with each other using only one pipe. The program waits for a positive integer input from the user. According to this input, these 3 processes one by one should print out a number starting from 0. For example, if the input is 10, the processes should print from 0 to 1 with printing just one number each and increase it by one. Grandson prints out the first number. He prints 0 first and using the pipe channel he sends the next number to process child. Process child prints, increases the number by one and sends it to the parent process. Parent process prints the number, increases it by one and sends it to the child process. Like this until one of them reaches the number which was input by the user.

For inputs 1,3,5,7,9 my program prints till 2,4,6,8,10 including these numbers, which is not correct.
For inputs 4,8 my program prints till numbers 4 and 8, but keeps waiting and doesn't return anything.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

volatile int flag = 0;

void SigHandler(int s)
{
    signal(SIGUSR1, SigHandler);
    flag = 1;
}

int main()
{
    pid_t pid;
    int fd[2];
    int count=0, countMax, queue=0;
    scanf("%d",&countMax);

    signal(SIGUSR1, SigHandler);

    if(pipe(fd) < 0)
    {
        perror("pipe\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if((pid=fork()) < 0)
    {
        perror("fork\n");
        return 2;
    }
    else if(pid == 0)
    {
        //SON
        pid = fork();
        if(pid<0)
        {
            perror("fork\n");
            return 3;
        }
        else if(pid == 0)
        {
            //GRANDSON
            while(count < countMax)
            {
                if(!flag)
                    pause();
                flag = 0;
                read(fd[0], &count, sizeof(int));
                printf("grandson %d\n", count++);
                fflush(stdout);
                write(fd[1], &count, sizeof(int));
                kill(getppid(), SIGUSR1);
            }
            close(fd[0]);
            close(fd[1]);
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
        //SON
            flag = 0;
            kill(pid, SIGUSR1);
            while(count < countMax)
            {
                if(!flag)
                    pause();
                flag = 0;
                read(fd[0], &count, sizeof(int));
                printf("son %d\n", count++);
                fflush(stdout);
                write(fd[1], &count, sizeof(int));
                if(queue == 0)
                {
                    kill(getppid(), SIGUSR1);
                    queue = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    kill(pid, SIGUSR1);
                    queue = 0;
                }
            }
            close(fd[0]);
            close(fd[1]);
            return 0;
        
        }
    }
    else
    {
    //FATHER
        write(fd[1], &count, sizeof(int));
        kill(pid,SIGUSR1);
        fflush(stdout);
            while(count < countMax)
            {
                if(count>=countMax)
                    raise(SIGINT);
                if(!flag)
                    pause();
                flag = 0;
                read(fd[0], &count, sizeof(int));
                printf("father %d\n", count++);
                fflush(stdout);
                write(fd[1], &count, sizeof(int));
                kill(pid, SIGUSR1);
            }
        close(fd[0]);
        close(fd[1]);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't actually described what the program is supposed to do. That is, what is the formal definition of "ping pong" for this task? The example output is good but you also need to describe the overall intent of the program. Also, please describe what you get instead of the expected behaviour.

Comment: I reviewed it, can you please reopen the question?

Comment: Processes are genderless.  Never"son", always "child".

Comment: If you are using signals to communicate, then you are violating the condition that the processes must only communicate via one pipe.

Comment: Well, signals are used here only for the synchronization of the queue of outputs and only one pipe seems enough for this type of connection where only one process at the same time prints, increases the integer and gives the flag to the next process in the queue, why do you think the condition is violated?

Comment: Do I understand correct that you want the processes (p=parent, c=child, g=grandchild) to become active for printing the numbers in a specific order like `p - c - g - p - c - g - ...` or `p - c - g - c - p - c - g - ...`? **Please clarify this in your question.** If more than one process tries to read from the same pipe, you cannot control which process gets the data. Even the process that wrote the data can get the data back itself. This is unlikely in your case because the other 2 processes are likely to be already waiting in `read`. Bigger data could even be partially read by 2 processes.

Comment: You try to use signals and `pause` to keep the processes waiting until they are notified by the currently active process to avoid that the wrong process reads the data. There might be bugs or race conditions in your implementation. I suggest to add comments to your code to explain the intended behavior. (In general the concept of 3 processes with always two of them waiting for a signal and one being active doesn't seem to be very useful for real applications.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added some debug output to the program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

volatile int flag = 0;

void SigHandler(int s)
{
    signal(SIGUSR1, SigHandler);
    flag = 1;
}

int main()
{
    pid_t pid;
    int fd[2];
    int count=0, countMax, queue=0;
    setvbuf(stderr, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    printf("enter maximum count: ");
    scanf("%d",&countMax);

    signal(SIGUSR1, SigHandler);

    if(pipe(fd) < 0)
    {
        perror("pipe\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if((pid=fork()) < 0)
    {
        perror("fork\n");
        return 2;
    }
    else if(pid == 0)
    {
        //SON
        pid = fork();
        if(pid<0)
        {
            perror("fork\n");
            return 3;
        }
        else if(pid == 0)
        {
            //GRANDSON
            while(count < countMax)
            {
                if(!flag)
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "@ grandchild pause\n");
                    pause();
                }
                flag = 0;
                fprintf(stderr, "@ grandchild read (after pause)\n");
                read(fd[0], &count, sizeof(int));
                printf("grandson %d\n", count++);
                fflush(stdout);
                write(fd[1], &count, sizeof(int));
                fprintf(stderr, "@ grandchild signal child\n");
                kill(getppid(), SIGUSR1);
            }
            fprintf(stderr, "@ grandchild done\n");
            close(fd[0]);
            close(fd[1]);
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
        //SON
            flag = 0;
            kill(pid, SIGUSR1);
            while(count < countMax)
            {
                if(!flag)
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "- child pause\n");
                    pause();
                }
                flag = 0;
                fprintf(stderr, "- child read (after pause)\n");
                read(fd[0], &count, sizeof(int));
                printf("son %d\n", count++);
                fflush(stdout);
                write(fd[1], &count, sizeof(int));
                if(queue == 0)
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "- child signal parent\n");
                    kill(getppid(), SIGUSR1);
                    queue = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "- child signal grandchild\n");
                    kill(pid, SIGUSR1);
                    queue = 0;
                }
            }
            fprintf(stderr, "- child done\n");
            close(fd[0]);
            close(fd[1]);
            return 0;
        
        }
    }
    else
    {
    //FATHER
        write(fd[1], &count, sizeof(int));
        kill(pid,SIGUSR1);
        fflush(stdout);
            while(count < countMax)
            {
                if(count>=countMax)
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "# parent raise SIGINT\n");
                    raise(SIGINT);
                }
                if(!flag)
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "# parent pause\n");
                    pause();
                }
                flag = 0;
                fprintf(stderr, "# parent read (after pause)\n");
                read(fd[0], &count, sizeof(int));
                printf("father %d\n", count++);
                fflush(stdout);
                write(fd[1], &count, sizeof(int));
                fprintf(stderr, "# parent signal child\n");
                kill(pid, SIGUSR1);
            }
        fprintf(stderr, "# parent done\n");
        close(fd[0]);
        close(fd[1]);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

With input `4` I get this output:

```
enter maximum count: 4                                                                                                                           
# parent pause                                                                                                                                   
- child pause                                                                                                                                    
@ grandchild read (after pause)                                                                                                                  
grandson 0                                                                                                                                       
@ grandchild signal child                                                                                                                        
@ grandchild pause                                                                                                                               
- child read (after pause)                                                                                                                       
son 1                                                                                                                                            
- child signal parent                                                                                                                            
- child pause                                                                                                                                    
# parent read (after pause)                                                                                                                      
father 2                                                                                                                                         
# parent signal child                                                                                                                            
# parent pause                                                                                                                                   
- child read (after pause)                                                                                                                       
son 3                                                                                                                                            
- child signal grandchild                                                                                                                        
- child done                                                                                                                                     
@ grandchild read (after pause)                                                                                                                  
grandson 4                                                                                                                                       
@ grandchild signal child                                                                                                                        
@ grandchild done
```

As you can see, at the end the child has already left the loop. The grandchild tries to send a signal to the child which will no longer react, and the parent is waiting for a signal in `pause`, but no process will send a signal to the parent.

This behavior depends on the input value.

**Edit**

A modified version of the original program which fixes the problem shown here, can be found in Tevfik Oğuzhan AKSOY's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64973727/10622916).

Comment: Hello, thanks to your debug output I found out how to solve the problem in my program, at input 4k(where k>=1 & k is a natural number), the program was actually waiting because the parent process wasn't aware of what's going on between grandchild and child processes, so it kept waiting as you mentioned and it printed some extra data for the input 2k-1, solved this through some if conditions after read function. So thanks a lot for your support!!

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

volatile int flag = 0;

void SigHandler(int s)
{
    signal(SIGUSR1, SigHandler);
    flag = 1;
}

int main()
{
    pid_t pid;
    pid_t pidFather = getpid();
    int fd[2];
    int count=0, countMax, queue=0;
   
    scanf("%d",&countMax);

    signal(SIGUSR1, SigHandler);

    if(pipe(fd) < 0)
    {
        perror("pipe\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if((pid=fork()) < 0)
    {
        perror("fork\n");
        return 2;
    }
    else if(pid == 0)
    {
        //SON
        pid = fork();
        if(pid<0)
        {
            perror("fork\n");
            return 3;
        }
        else if(pid == 0)
        {
            //GRANDSON
            while(count < countMax)
            {
                if(!flag)
                {
                    pause();
                }
                flag = 0;
                read(fd[0], &count, sizeof(int));
        if(count<=countMax)
        {
                    printf("grandson %d\n", count++);
                    fflush(stdout);
                    write(fd[1], &count, sizeof(int));
            kill(getppid(), SIGUSR1);
        }
            }
            close(fd[0]);
            close(fd[1]);
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            //SON
            flag = 0;
            kill(pid, SIGUSR1);
            while(count < countMax)
            {
                if(!flag)
                {
                    pause();
                }
                flag = 0;
                read(fd[0], &count, sizeof(int));
        if(count<=countMax)
        {
                    printf("son %d\n", count++);
                    fflush(stdout);
                    write(fd[1], &count, sizeof(int));
                    if(queue == 0)
                    {
                                kill(getppid(), SIGUSR1);
                            queue = 1;
                    }
                    else if(queue != 0)
                {
                        kill(pid, SIGUSR1);
                        queue = 0;
                    }
        }
            }
        kill(getppid(), SIGUSR1);
            close(fd[0]);
            close(fd[1]);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //FATHER
    write(fd[1], &count, sizeof(int));
        kill(pid,SIGUSR1);
        fflush(stdout);
        while(count < countMax)
        {
            if(!flag)
            {
                pause();
            }
            flag = 0;
            read(fd[0], &count, sizeof(int));
        if(count<=countMax)
        {
            printf("father %d\n", count++);
            fflush(stdout);
                write(fd[1], &count, sizeof(int));
                kill(pid, SIGUSR1);
        }
        }
        close(fd[0]);
    close(fd[1]);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add some explanation to this answer. I guess it is a working version of the code, isn't it? If this is the case, I can add a link to this answer to my answer.

Comment: I just tested the code with different input values. I noticed a possible problem with input 8 or 16. The sequence for 8 is grandson 0 son 1 father 2 son 3 grandson 4 son 5
father 6 son 7 father 8. Shouldn't the value 8 get printed by the grandchild as it is in case of input 9?

Comment: Yes, I thought this was the answer, in my system everything went well, though, somehow father and grandson go into a race condition, I can't understand why. Grandson should print every 4k(for k>=1). Actually variable queue in son's part determines whose turn it is to print. Instead of grandson, sometimes father wins the race... There shouldn't even be a race condition, but even if the variable queue says that it is grandson's turn, somehow the signal is sent to the father...